# How to calculate an average with data that exceeds measurement limits

Tags: statistics

I have problem where there is a fair amount of “exceeds instrumentation limits” data. I want to use the data, but I’m not sure how to do so legitimately. Here is an example. Lets say you have a rain gauge that has a maximum capacity of 10 cm. You 100 daily measures of something less than 10 cm, but 20 days the rain gauge was overflowing. Obviously it rained at leas 10 cm, but you don’t know how much more than 10 cm it rained that day. There is no other data you can use for confirmation. I How would you try and calculate average daily rainfall for the time period?

Here is tiny table of fictitious data to demonstrate my issue

```
Day     Precip     note

1     5.4
2     2.1
3     10     (exceeds detection limit)
4     8.5
5     10     (exceeds detection limit)
6     0
7     1.4
8     10     (exceeds detection limit)
9     3.8
10     0
```

Comment: Do all gauges have the maximum capacity of 10 cm? In this case, you can only calculate the average given that it is less than 10 cm and you would have to exclude the sample points for which the limit is exceeded.

I would additionally estimate the probability that the limit is exceeded / not exceeded as a summary statistic to get a better overview.

Comment: For this example, let's assume that all gauges have a maximum capacity of 10 cm. This is a case where we would know that it rained "at least" 10 cm, but we don't know how much more than 10 cm. It is tempting to use the 10 cm measures are say something like, "the average daily rainfall was at least 5.12 cm" If we exclude the 10 cm values, then the have an average rainfall of 3.03 with the qualifies of 3 measures were excluded because they exceeded instrument capacity... or something to that effect.